# How to render below array of objects in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, object

I have received below array of objects as a response from Rest API,

```
var companyDatas = {
    "accounts": {
        "company 1 ": {
            "id": "4",
            "enabled": "1"
        },
        "company 2": {
            "id": "2",
            "enabled": "1"
        },
        "company 3": {
            "id": "1",
            "enabled": "1"
        }
    }
  };
  
  const [companyData, setcompanyData] = useState([companyDatas]);
```

But i have a difficulty rendering below array of objects as following format.

```
company 1  
id:4
company 2  
id:2
company 3 
id:1
```

so far i have tried below code ,where response is the list of json i have received from rest api via post.
response.accounts

which gives me below list of objects, but now i am not able to display only comapany name and id ..

```
    "company 1 ": {
        "id": "4",
        "enabled": "1"
    },
    "company 2": {
        "id": "2",
        "enabled": "1"
    },
    "company 3": {
        "id": "3",
        "enabled": "1"
    }
```

Comment: First it's not an array of objects. Second, please share what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @technophyle commented, please share what you're tried next time. I assumed that object is stored in some sort of variable, I've called it `companyData` for now.

Here's how you would achieve your desired output

```
export default function App() {

  const companyDatas = {
    "accounts": {
        "company 1 ": {
            "id": "4",
            "enabled": "1"
        },
        "company 2": {
            "id": "2",
            "enabled": "1"
        },
        "company 3": {
            "id": "1",
            "enabled": "1"
        }
    }
  };

  const [companyData, setCompanyData] = useState(companyDatas)

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {
        Object.entries(companyData.accounts)
        .map(([company, accountData]) => (
          <View key={company}>
            <Text>{company}</Text>
            <Text>id: {accountData.id}</Text>
          </View>
        ))
      }
    </View>
  );
}
```

Using `Object.entries()` will give you an array of company objects as such:

```
[
    [
        "company 1 ",
        {
            "id": "4",
            "enabled": "1"
        }
    ],
    [
        "company 2",
        {
            "id": "2",
            "enabled": "1"
        }
    ],
    [
        "company 3",
        {
            "id": "1",
            "enabled": "1"
        }
    ]
]
```

Then using `.map(([company, accountData]))` we can assign the data to these variables. Then you simply use those as `{company}` and `{accountData}` in your  JSX.

Edit:

I didn't notice the useState earlier. First I'd like to ask why `companyData` is stored as `useState([companyData])`, because that's why it's giving that error. Removing the `[]` from it will fix it.

Comment: First of all thank you , since i am storing those value in usestate as in my question above , i am getting Cannot convert undefined value to object  for Object.entries part , any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Hey @James! Apologies for the late reply. I've edited the previous answer on how to fix that error.